# How to make pointer/reference on element in vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

I have two vectors and for some elements (not all) i need them to be connected ~ if i delete/change this element in one vector it should be removed/changed in both.

Something similar like pointers:

```
int r = 10;
int *p= &r;
*p = 3;
```

For example in next code it should change myvector2[0].a to 7.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct elt {
    int a, b, c;
};

int main()
{

    vector<elt> myvector;
    vector <elt> myvector2;
    elt elt1 = {1,3,3};

    myvector.push_back(elt1);
    elt *elt2 = &elt1;
    myvector2.push_back(*elt2);

    myvector[0].a=7;

    cout << myvector[0].a << endl; //7
    cout << myvector2[0].a << endl; //1

    return 0;
}
```

How can i make this possible? Please help!!!

Comment: I question the validity & wisdom of having the same "thing" in two `vectors`.  Commonly one needs to build an index.  In that case, one `vector` has the "thing", and the other meerly points to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As tgmath explained, the issue is that you wind up with two different objects in your vectors, as the standard containers store elements by value. I would recommend that you use shared pointers to properly maintain the lifetime of the objects (note this uses C++11 features):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct elt {
    int a, b, c;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<elt>> myvector;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<elt>> myvector2;
    auto elt1 = std::make_shared<elt>(elt {1,3,3});

    myvector.push_back(elt1);
    myvector2.push_back(elt1);

    myvector[0]->a=7;

    std::cout << myvector[0]->a << std::endl; //7
    std::cout << myvector2[0]->a << std::endl; //7

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I got you correctly, this solves only "change" problem from the original post. Any way to handle "removal" part of the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Pointers and references (and iterators) to elements of `std::vector` are invalidated whenever the vector reallocates, which can happen during insertion. So you can only keep these if the vector is guaranteed not to reallocate for the lifetime of the pointer/reference. This can be achieved if you don't insert into the vector, or if you call `reserve()` on it before you start (and before you acquire the pointer/reference/iterator), extending its capacity so that no reallocations will be necessary.

If you can't guarantee that, your only option is to keep the index instead of a pointer/reference. Of course, you will also need access to the vector itself for this to work, but you should be able to keep a pointer or reference to it, e.g.

```
typedef std::pair<std::vector<elt>*, size_t> ReferenceIntoVector;
```

Answer (score 1):

`myvector2.push_back(*elt2);` adds a copy of `*elt2` into `myvector2`

This means that both vector have their own copy of the `elt` object. And both of them are distinct from `elt1`.

If you change the one in the first vector, the second does not change at all.
For this purpose yiu would need a `std::vector<elt*>` to have different pointers to the same object in different vectors.

Comment: And this is gonna blow, when first vector's iterators (and so addresses) get invalidated (e.g. after push_back).

Comment: I'd consider `std::vector<elt*>` is quite bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no built in way to automatically remove an element from one vector if you happen to delete it from another.

In my opinion there are two different challenges here:

1. How can I update an element pointed to by one list to be updated in another?
2. How can I remove an element from one list, and have that removed from the other?

The first question is already answered in the other posts: Use std::shared pointers instead of your native pointers. They are just as fast and will take care of all the memory management for you.

**Please note:** That this approach will only work as long as you are only changing the value of the element pointed to by the shared pointer, and not *what* the shared pointer is pointing to.

In other words/code:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<elt>> vec1, vec2;
// Insert some elements
vec1.push_back( std::make_shared( elt{ 1, 2, 3} );
vec2.push_back( vec1.back() );

vec1[0]->x = 5;                     // OK, updated in both vectors.
vec1[0] = make_shared(elt {3,2,1}); // Error: vec1[0] is pointing to a new object.
```

The other challenge is much harder, how can you automatically delete an element from both vectors. The short answer is "You can't", the slightly longer is, you can but not directly.

**Approach 1: Setting deleted elements to `nullptr`.**

This approach is a bit dirty an not something I would recommend as it requires all code that use either vector to check whether an element is `nullptr`.

```
// Encapsulate the object inside a `std::unique_ptr`
std::vector< std::shared_ptr< std::unique_ptr< elt >>> vec1, vec2;

// Adding elements are done similarly as before
vec1.push_back( std::make_shared( std::make_unique( elt{ 1, 2, 3} )));
vec2.push_back( vec1.back() );

// Now to delete a element you would do as follows
vec1[0]->reset(nullptr);          // Flag this element as deleted
vec1[0]->erase( vec1.begin() );   // Remove element from vec1

// Now let us assume we are iterating through the other vector at a later time:
for (auto it = vec2.begin(); it != vec2.end(); ++it ) { // Using iterators makes the code cleaner.
    if ( **it == nullptr ) { // If the unique_ptr == nullptr
       it = erase(it);
    else {
       etl & the_value = ***it; // Yes you need all three, one for the iterator, one for the shared_ptr and one for the unique_ptr...
    }
}
```

As you can see this quickly gets hairy. But if that is all you need it can work.

**Approach 2: (The better in my opinion) Is to use the Observer/Observed Design Pattern.**

In order to implement this pattern you will need to exchange your vector for another class. Let us make a simple example:

```
// First, create an interface describing all operations you want to be
// informed about.
template<class T>
class SharedElementListObserver {
protected:
    void elementDeleted( const shared_ptr<T> & elem ) = 0;
}

template<class T>
class SharedElementList : public SharedElementListObserver<T> {
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> data;
   std::unordered_set<SharedElementListObserver*> observers;
public:
   void push_back( const T & elem ) { data.push_back( std::make_shared<T>( elem )); }
   void push_back( std::shared_ptr &sptr ) { data.push_back( sptr ); }

   shared_ptr<T> operator[] (int index) { 
       return data[index]; 
   }
   shared_ptr<const T> operator[] (int index ) const { 
       return std::static_pointer_cast<const T>( data[index] ); 
   }

   // This will cause all instances of elem in all lists
   // linked either directly and indirectly to this 
   // to be removed.
   void delete( int idx ) {
        if (idx >= 0 && idx < data.size() ) {
             shared_ptr<T> temp = data[idx];
             data.erase( data.begin() + idx );
             for (auto observer : observers) {
                 observer->elementDeleted(temp);
             }
         }
   }

   // Link another list to this one to listen to deletions.
   void link( SharedElementListObserver* observer ) {
        if (observer == this) return;
        else if (observers.insert(observer).second) {
            observer->observers.insert(this);
        }
   }

   // Unlink previously linked observer.
   void unlink(SharedElementListObserver* observer) {
       observer->observers.erase(this);
       this->observers.erase(observer);
   }

protected:
   void elementDeleted( shared_ptr<T> & elem ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ) {
            if (data[i] == elem)
                delete(i);  // Not infinite loop, because of test above.
            else
                i++;
        }
   }


   // You also need to write an operator=, a copy-constructor and a destructor
   // that ensures that there are no dead observers in the observers list.
};
```

Depending on your assumptions this class can be implemented in a number of different ways. Some probably simpler than what I just did.

Please let me know if there are any errors in the above code.